# How is this Ruby class able to have this definition in omniauth-oauth2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So looking at this [oauth2 strategy](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth2) from intridea, how does *uid{ raw_info['id'] }* not have the below Ruby class error out?  It looks like they're trying to define an attribute with a block??

```
require 'omniauth-oauth2'

module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    class SomeSite < OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2
      # Give your strategy a name.
      option :name, "some_site"

      # This is where you pass the options you would pass when
      # initializing your consumer from the OAuth gem.
      option :client_options, {:site => "https://api.somesite.com"}

      # These are called after authentication has succeeded. If
      # possible, you should try to set the UID without making
      # additional calls (if the user id is returned with the token
      # or as a URI parameter). This may not be possible with all
      # providers.
      uid{ raw_info['id'] }

      info do
        {
          :name => raw_info['name'],
          :email => raw_info['email']
        }
      end

      extra do
        {
          'raw_info' => raw_info
        }
      end

      def raw_info
        @raw_info ||= access_token.get('/me').parsed
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I tried the following in the irb console and received an error

```
2.1.2 :016 >  class M
2.1.2 :017?>   a { callb }
2.1.2 :018?>   def callb
2.1.2 :019?>     "hello"
2.1.2 :020?>     end
2.1.2 :021?>   end
NoMethodError: undefined method `a' for M:Class
```

Comment: My guess is that `uid` isn't a local variable, but a method that accepts a block.  You'll have to keep digging through the source to find it.

Comment: Thanks Phillip you are right - it comes from Omniauth, one of the gem's dependencies in /lib/omniauth/strategy.rb line 90 I believe.